# Xcode doesn't see variable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, variables, var

I just starting my way in Swift, now trying to create simple RPG (**R**ole-**p**laying video **g**ame) and I take this issue. I linked a label from the 2-nd view controller to the swift file and I can't access this variable. I just writing a name of var, but Xcode doesn't display predictive and display error when I writing name myself.
Any way to solve it pls?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WVmw.png)
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx0at.png)

Comment: You have to put the line into a method (`func`)

Comment: That is because the scope of variable doesn't match. You should assign the text to label inside functions not directly inside class

Comment: put **youChoosed.text = yourChoice**  inside **viewDidLoad**

Comment: show your code what you write

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this kind of codes in methods (func keyword).
In your code, type it into viewDidLoad() and init your variable (just like `var yourChoise:String = ""`)

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()
   youChoosed.text = yourChoise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode will provide predictive text if you start typing inside of `viewDidLoad()`. Behind the scenes, your app is set up to call that method when the view is loaded from the storyboard and is ready to be presented.